# Probability involving three cards

Tags: probability

There are three bags, with two cards in each bag having $1$ and $2$ on those two cards. What is the probability when withdrawing one card from each bag that the sum of card values is $5$?

I found an answer is $3/8$, but I think I didn't understand how to solve...

Comment: You begin by describing "two cards in a bag".  Then you ask about withdrawing "a card from 3rd bag".  How did we go from having one bag to having a "3rd bag"?

Comment: Im sorry :) there are 3 bag it was mb sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $8$ ways to pull the cards in total. Of these $3$ give us the answer we want:

$$122, 212, 221$$

So the probability of pulling $5$ is:

$$P(\text{total is 5})=\frac38$$